# Programmatically create a ToolStripDropDown

Tags: c#, toolstripdropdown

How can I programmatically create a `ToolStripDropDown` in a winform project ? I want to associate this item to a `TextBox` (showing last entries) and it appears when clicking on a `Button`.

It should be on the red line :

[image]

Edit : I actually have :

```
Class MyClass : UserControl
{
    //Created in designer :
    // Button buttonName;
    // TextBox textboxName;
    // List<String> lastNames;

    // I want to create
    ToolStripDropDown toolStripName;

    public MyClass ()
    {
        toolStripName = new ToolStripDropDown();
        toolStripName.OwnerItem = textboxName; // Want to define the textbox as owner
        buttonName.Click += ButtonName_Click;
        toolStripName.Items = lastNames; // I want to display the last names saved
    }

    private void ButtonName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripName.Show();
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work. I never used a `ToolStripDropDown` and I don't know how to use it.

Comment: You have to show us code that duplicates it for us.

Comment: What is the nature of the problem you are encountering?  Your question is too general at the moment

Comment: Actually I just have a `Button buttonName` and a `TextBox textBoxName`. I want to create a `ToolStripDropDown` element. This element appears on the box bot when clicking on button. It will contain a list of string.

Comment: @SpaceUser7448 I added my actual code to be less general, but it is a draft.

Comment: OwnerItem has to be a ToolStrip item, so that can't be a normal TextBox control.  Is that a standard button or a ToolStrip button?  Why not use a ToolStripDropDownButton instead?

Comment: @LarsTech I did some researches and I found ToolStripDropDown, I don't know the difference with ToolStripDropDownButton. I'll take a look